# (Alternatives to) Sensory Deprivation for Concentration & Productivity

Tags: software-development, productivity, concentration

I found that my concentration and productivity are higher (probably up to 50%) when I wear ear plugs and when I work in a relatively dark room (shutters almost closed). That's probably not surprising as I am a software developer. I know that it is not uncommon for developers to prefer to work during the night - which achieves, more or less, the same effect.

My question is how to fit this in a "normal" workplace? Most offices these days are open plan - which brings plenty of noise. Also, there is a higher level of visual stimuli, e.g. people walking next to your desk.

Working from home (WFH) seems to be the best solution - I have a room at home which I keep mostly dark when working and I wear ear plugs. Unfortunately, not all employers are happy with WFH.

So how can I best achieve a similar effect in a normal office? I found a relatively good solution for the noise by wearing heavy duty ear muffs (like the ones used by operators of noisy machinery). I attract some weird looks in the office but this is not a big issue for me. The thing I haven't found a solution for is the visual stimuli. It is less bad compared to the noise but it still reduces my concentration and productivity by ~10-20%.

Which prompted me to ask: is anyone else dealing with these sort of issues? Is there something else I can try to help with keeping focus and concentration while at work?

Comment: A [Timothy Leary tank aka Samadhi-tank](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating) crossed my mind, just make sure you have waterproof office equipment and a generous financial department.. ;)

Comment: "That's probably not surprising as I am a software developer." Well, it pretty is actually...

Answer (score 5):

Good quality active noise-cancelling headphones (with or without music) and lightly tinted/filtered lenses (I find blue-filters greatly beneficial) in glasses (even if you don't require corrective lenses) are the best you are going to reasonably manage in an open-plan environment.

It's not a perfect solution by any means - but it helps significantly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using time-management techniques to focus your productivity so that you don't feel too distracted by other things happening.

When I need to buckle down, I write myself a to-do list and work my way through that.  I found that simply concentrating more lessens my tendency to be distracted by things.

I also find that the act of putting on headphones heightens my tendency to work more (it puts me "in the zone" and passively tells colleagues that I'm "busy").  Conversely, *removing* the headphones allows me some time to relax a little and engage in my surroundings because too much "zone time" isn't always a good thing.